# Retrieving and comparing very large data sets with multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql, .net

The requirement: I have multiple databases (Oracle / SQL Server) etc. From database I need to get large/huge amount of data into a c# program and compare the data with one and other. Each data file from a dataset will have a key (not 100% unique, might have duplicates as well), using that key I can compare other dataset files/databases.

Each database will return approx around 1.5 million rows. I have 5 different databases from which I will be getting data. i.e 7.5 million rows will loaded into my program.

1. What is the best way to load the data into the program (currently each SQL takes 5 minutes on the database side). Load into CSV and then read in C#? Any other ideas?
2. I am planning to load data into HashSet in c#, is that good option?

> ```
> DB 1:
> Account   Amount
> 1234  1
> 9999  66
>
> DB 2:
> Account   Amount
> 1234  2
> 9999  66
>
> DB 3:
> Account   Amount
> 1234  1
> 9999  66
>
> DB 4:
> Account   Amount
> 1234  10
> 9999  66
>
> After comparing the output looks like
> Account   DB1 Amt DB1 Amt DB3 Amt DB4 Amt Match?
> 1234  1   2   1   10  No
> 9999  66  66  66  66  Yes
> ```

Comment: If it is not unique then it is not a key.  What is a data file from a dataset?  Where does the 2 come from on DB1?

Comment: Balm, are you talking about final table in orginal/first post? Its an aligement issue 2 belongs to DB2.

Comment: Personally, I would get the extracts from the databases and import then into SQL Server and then write SQL to compare (which is easy with MS SQL Server with the EXCEPT keyword)

Comment: Then fix the alignment.  Convert it to code {} and it will align.  What do you mean by not unique?  Fix the question.  You cannot use a hashset if you don't have a unique key.

Answer (score 0):

With respect, this is not a huge problem. It's a medium sized problem, in which you must process 7.5 megarows.  In your example these rows seem to be relatively short.  If you have access to a computer with more than two GB of RAM, you can probably do this whole job in RAM fairly easily. A typical 2011-era laptop can do that. Almost any Win x64 laptop can do it in RAM.

You asked whether you should draw your data directly from the database systems or from CSVs. If you're planning to use this system in production, you should stick to working with the database systems. That avoids the possibility of working with stale data by mistake.

From your question it looks like the `Account` values in your various systems match each other exactly, without a lot of monkey-business about fuzzy matching.  That is, it seems that an account is called "1234" in several databases, and not "1234" in one of them, "1234-001" in another, and "A1234-2014" in a third.  That is very good news. It means you can use such things as HashSets to handle them in memory.

You probably should set your system up so it can process either all data or an arbitrary subset of `Account` values. For example, you might allow a subset to be specified as '1000' - '1999'. This will come in very handy for testing, because you'll be able to do short runs with just a few thousand accounts.  This should mean you can get everything working with short-running subset queries. When you're satisfied that everything is working well, you can start a production run and go home for the night.

Notice that you might also, if this is a one-off job, simply install some DBMS (MySQL or PostgreSQL would be good open source choices) on your personal machine, load the various extracts from various database systems into tables in it, and do JOINs on them.

Finally, if you are inheriting data of unknown quality, Google lets you download a very helpful data-inspection and cleaning tool called [OpenRefine](https://github.com/OpenRefine).

Comment: Thanks Ollie. But couple of other database queries taking 20-30 to return the data. For forums, I just gave an overview of my question. Also I should have mention this earlier, the data I am getting is old (last 24 months).

Comment: I strongly support Ollie's suggestion to process subsets of the data.  This allows you to begin examining the results while processing another set.  But even more important (to me, at least) is this allows you to handle interruptions by picking up where you left off.  I expect that will be very beneficial.

Comment: @DeadZone  yeah, no kidding, this kind of numbercrunching job hardly ever completes in one run.